# Passing new line from command line to PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

How to pass a new line character from the command line to PowerShell?

```
// MyScript.ps1:
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
    [Parameter()] $Param
)

Write-Host $Param

// Command line (not PowerShell - cmd.exe!)
powershell.exe -File MyScript.ps1 -Param "First`nSecond"
```

Does not work. Also using the command line's new line character `\n` does not work. So how to pass a new line tothe command line?

Answer (score 4):

A workaround would be to use any other character, e.g. `\n` in the command line, and replace it within PowerShell:

```
$x = $param.Replace("\n", "`n")
```

This works, however, it is of course a hack and not my preferred solution.

Comment: You can use (backtick n) if you duplicate the backtick in `replace` call. `$x = $param.Replace("``n", "`n")`

Answer (score 2):

When calling from CMD with a variable, I had to pass the parameter as a literal (using `'` instead of `"`).

Sample **pstest.ps1**:

```
Write-Host "Without Replace:"
Write-Host $args[0]

Write-Host #Blank Space for Readability
Write-Host "With Replace:"
Write-Host $args[0].Replace("\n", "`n")
```

Call from CMD and results:

```
> set "tmpvar=blar1 de \nblar2"
> powershell.exe .\pstest.ps1 '%tmpvar%'

Without Replace:
blar1 de \nblar2

With Replace:
blar1 de
blar2
```

Comment: Uh, a reply after 7 years - thanks. Upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

There is a special character as in `First Line◙Second Line`.

Comment: This seems to be some special new line character which is neither known by powershell nor by the command line. It indeed works with `Write-Host` but is otherwise not the same as "backtick n", e.g. not accepted by cmdlets like `ConvertFrom-StringData`. Pity :-(

Answer (score 0):

You need a carriage return and line feed:

```
`r`n
```

So this should work:

```
powershell.exe -File MyScript.ps1 -Param "First`r`nSecond"
```

Comment: Thanks, however, Write-Host does not add a new line but instead outputs ``r``n. Also if I pass my parameter on to `ConvertFrom-StringData` it does not recognize the new line...

Comment: Hm, I tryed the script (saved it as MyScript.ps1) and it outputs the string correctly in two lines. Can you just try to Write-Host "First`r`nSecond"

Comment: @jisaak Now try raw `cmd.exe`. The script does work if you type that command at Powershell prompt, but not in a cmd.exe prompt.

Comment: ah, I missed that part